# Printing indices of 3-dimensional variable in PuLP for scheduling

Tags: python, optimization, scheduling, pulp

I am working with SolverStudio (Excel add-in) and PuLP (Python-based optimization language) to create a tool that assigns students to working places.

This is the variable whose indices I want to print:

`# Decision variable, =1 if student s is assigned to working place w on day d; 0 otherwise
Assignment = LpVariable.dicts("Assignment",(Students,Working_places,Days),0,1,LpBinary)`

For each working place and day, I want to output the name of the student who is assigned there, in order to create a schedule.

My current approach is:

```
for w in Working_places:
    for d in Days:
        for s in Students:
            if Assignment[s][w][d] == 1:
                Schedule[w,d] = Name[s]
```

`Schedule[w,d]` is an empty 2d parameter defined in SolverStudio and `Name[s]` contains the names of the students.

I placed the code sequence at different positions of the model. It doesn't make a difference, whether it is before or after the `prob.solve()` statement.

Currently, `Schedule[w,d]` is being filled completely with the name of the last student in the list of students.

I observed that the if-clause is completely ignored. I can remove it and the same output is generated.

Is there a different way to tell Python "for each working place and day, print the assigned student"?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake myself in the meantime:

`for w in Working_places:
    for d in Days:
        for s in Students:
            if Assignment[s][w][d].varValue == 1:
                Schedule[w,d] = Name[s]`